# Setting tool tip on a Text Control

Tags: text, wix, windows-installer, controls, txtextcontrol

In my wix project i have a text control element
how do i set a ToolTip text on that text control element
I have tried this:

```
<Control Id="ANYIDVALUE" Type="Text" X="XAXIS" Y="YAXIS" Height="HEIGHT" Width="WIDTH" Transparent="TRANSPARENTVALUE" Property="ANYPROPERTYNAME" Text="ANYTEXT" ToolTip="TOOLTIPTEXT" TabSkip="no">
</Control>
```

But this does not work.
Can anybody help, Thanx in advance.

Comment: Could you please explain "does not work" in more details? Does it though an error? Is it just displaying something you don't expect? Note that `Tooltip` attribute is not of `Formatted` type and won't expand properties - just plain text is allowed there.

Comment: By does not work, i meant to say that it is not displaying the ToolTip on the text.
Just the Text is getting displayed on the screen.